# What is the difference between WCF and WPF?

Tags: wpf, wcf

I am a naive developer and I am building up my concepts, I was asked to create a sample application in wcf, and so I am asking a bit subjective question here.
I want to know the diffrence and functionality of the above two, in which terms we prefer one over other?

Comment: a quick internet search would answer this.... They have nothing in common

Answer (score 27, accepted):

WCF = Windows COMMUNICATION Foundation

WPF = Windows PRESENTATION Foundation.

WCF deals with communication (in simple terms - sending and receiving data as well as formatting and serialization involved), WPF deals with presentation (UI)

Comment: When we have WCF Ria services what actually it depicts for our application?

Comment: @John Gathogo Thanks for the simple and straight forward answer! even a new programmer can understand!

Answer (score 16):

The quick answer is: Windows Presentation Foundation (WPF) is basically a way of displaying user interface. (see [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms754130.aspx))

Windows Communication Foundation (WCF) is a framework for creating service oriented applications. (see [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731082.aspx))

As for which one you should use, it depends on your requirement. Usually an application written in WPF, ASP.NET..etc called the WCF service to do some processing at the server-side and the service returns the result to the application that called it.

Answer (score 6):

**Windows Presentation Foundation (WPF)**

Next-Generation User Experiences. The Windows Presentation Foundation, WPF, provides a unified framework for building applications and high-fidelity experiences in Windows Vista that blend application UI, documents, and media content. WPF offers developers 2D and 3D graphics support, hardware-accelerated effects, scalability to different form factors, interactive data visualization, and superior content readability.

**Windows Communication Foundation (WCF)**

Windows Communication Foundation (WCF) is Microsoft’s unified programming model for building service-oriented applications. It enables developers to build secure, reliable, transacted solutions that integrate across platforms and interoperate with existing investments.

Answer (score 6):

- WPF is your FrontEnd (presentation: .htm, .xaml & .css, ..)
- WCF is your BackEnd app (services that involve server connections to acquire data for you to deliver to the FrontEnd to present). You can write WCF for RESTful model.
- WebAPI is for building services of RESTful model for 4.+ frameworks.

Answer (score 2):

Basically, if you are developing a client- server application. You may use WCF -> in order to make connection between client and server, WPF -> as client side to present the data.

Answer (score 0):

WCF = Windows Communication Foundation is used to build service-oriented applications.
WPF = Windows Presentation Foundation is used to write platform-independent applications.

Answer (score -2):

Windows communication Fundation(WCF) is used for connecting different applications and passing the data's between them using endpoints.

Windows Presentation Foundation is used for designing rich internet applications in the format of xaml.

Comment: WPF is for creating rich windows applications, not internet applications.